# The integral $\int \sqrt{\ x \sqrt[3]{\ x \sqrt[4]{\ x \sqrt[5]{\ x \cdots}}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have no idea how to solve the second question from [2018 MIT integration bee](http://www.mit.edu/~same/pdf/qualifying_round_2018_answers.pdf),

$$\int \sqrt{\ x \sqrt[3]{\ x \sqrt[4]{\ x \sqrt[5]{\ x \cdots}}}} dx = \frac{x^{e-1}}{e-1}.$$

I tried to to find a value for the roots and i tried converting it to a power, and I tried making a $u$ substitution but nothing worked out, while i think that the right approach to this question is to convert the roots to a power, i cant find the right approach to the question.

Comment: Show us first that you have attempted something...

Comment: What is an integration "bee" ? Why not an integration mosquito?

Comment: It's like a spelling bee -- a competition to see who's the best integrator. Has been going on for at least 40 years, probably more.

Comment: @John Hughes Thank you. Question from a beotian. I have improved my culture today...

Comment: And now I have learned the meaning of a new word : beotian. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanMarie well i tried to investigate the first part of the function  by converting the root to a power and then i tried to make a u substitution but that didnt work out

Comment: Seriously Jean Marie? Mosquito?

Comment: Guys i really need you help

Comment: The RHS suggests that it is a result from power rule, right?

Comment: @jkabrg  wow thank you so much, i cant thank you enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
I&=\int \sqrt{\ x\sqrt[3]{\ x\sqrt[4]{\ x\cdots}}}\,dx\\
I&=\int \sqrt{\ x}\cdot \sqrt{\ \sqrt[3]{\ x}}\cdot \sqrt{\ \sqrt[3]{\ \sqrt[4]{x}}}\cdots\,dx\\
I&=\int x^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/6}\cdot x^{1/24}\cdots\,dx\\
I&=\int x^{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}}\,dx\\
I&=\int x^{e-2}\,dx\\
I&=\frac{x^{e-1}}{e-1}+C
\end{align}